# Why aren't my Bootstrap buttons full width?

Tags: django, bootstrap-5

I am trying trying to integrate bootstrap into my Django site but it doesn't look quite right. I was looking for CSS clashes but the only stuff I could find is in the static folder and it just has admin related CSS. All my pages work its just the CSS that looks a bit off. Any help is great, thanks.

```
<!-- templates/base.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block nav %}
        <ul id="nav">
            <li>{% block nav-home %}<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>{% endblock %}</li>
        </ul>
        {% endblock %}
     <div id='content' class='main'>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
     </div>
      {% block scripts %}
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<!-- templates/registration/login.html -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Log in{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<section class="vh-100" style="background-color: #508bfc;">
  <div class="container py-5 h-100">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
        <div class="card shadow-2-strong" style="border-radius: 1rem;">
          <div class="card-body p-5 text-center">

            <h3 class="mb-5">Sign in</h3>

            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
              <input type="email" id="typeEmailX-2" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
              <label class="form-label" for="typeEmailX-2">Email</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
              <input type="password" id="typePasswordX-2" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
              <label class="form-label" for="typePasswordX-2">Password</label>
            </div>

            <!-- Checkbox -->
            <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-start mb-4">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="form1Example3" />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="form1Example3"> Remember password </label>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>

            <hr class="my-4">

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" style="background-color: #dd4b39;"
              type="submit"><i class="fab fa-google me-2"></i> Sign in with google</button>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary mb-2" style="background-color: #3b5998;"
              type="submit"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f me-2"></i>Sign in with facebook</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Expected:
[image: expected]

Actual:
[image: actual]

Comment: The `btn-block` class isn't working in Bootstrap 5, check documentation, there is an example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/buttons/

Comment: but there are other things like fonts, placeholders etc. that are wrong too not just buttons

Comment: As you have learned, your question could've been more specific. Please see [ask] for next time, and take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: The reason is that your markup has errors, with other things. I created a local HTML file and checked a couple of them. CDN files are loading like a charm, no problems with that. You need to fix those errors, and your page appearance will be much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the email and password input tags include

```
<input ..... placeholder="Email">
```

Doing this will put email inside of the text box.

If you do this...

```
<div class="form-outline mb-4">
    <label class="form-label" for="typePasswordX-2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="typePasswordX-2" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
          
</div>
```

The label will appear above the text box. If you do not want just get rid of the label tag. I recommend leaving it on as it helps with accessibility.

and add a

```
<br/>
```

tag between the buttons

Comment: Line breaks really shouldn't be used for layout. Wrap one or both buttons in divs or other block-level elements instead.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't with your library imports. It's with your syntax. Make sure you're following the correct documentation version.

[Inputs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/input-group/) won't have internal labels if you use `label` elements like that. Use `aria-label` and `placeholder` attributes on the `input` element instead.

[Buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/buttons/) aren't sized with `btn-block` in Bootstrap 5. Use the `w-100` [sizing class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/sizing/) instead.

Buttons don't have uppercase labels in Bootstrap 5, either. That screenshot must be from an earlier version.

And buttons won't have default margin. Use [spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/) as needed.

Font sizes are calculated and configured differently from earlier versions as well.